# Yii2: How to access parameters in Mail-view?

Tags: php, yii2

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('order-html', ['myVar' => 'HALLO' ])
->setTo(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
->setSubject('Ihre Trauring-Bestellung ist eingegangen')
->send();
```

How can I access the myVar-var in my mail-view order-html.php?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where are you going to use those variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

swiftmailer:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('other', ['myVar' => 'HALLO'])
                ->setFrom('from@example.com')
                ->setTo('to@example.com')
                ->setSubject('Message subject')
                ->send();
```

in other.php:

```
<?=$myVar; ?>
```

Comment: Help please I not working. ---- See you  please  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969709/how-get-parameters-from-compose-in-view-yii-2

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Yii::$app->mailer->compose('order-html'` you are actually calling a view and assigning the result of the view to the body of the email, so you would access the variables exactly how you would do in a view (because it is a view).