# how get parameters from compose() in view Yii-2?

Tags: yii, yii2

how get parameters from compose() in view Yii-2?

I try:

/controllers/SiteController

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('layouts/html.php', ['model' => 'trtrtrtrt',])
 ->setFrom('ergegergerger@gmail.com')
 ->setTo('ergergergegerg@mail.ru')
 ->setSubject('TEST')
 ->send();
```

mail/layouts/html.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\mail\BaseMailer;


/* @var $this \yii\web\View view component instance */
/* @var $message \yii\mail\MessageInterface the message being composed */
/* @var $content string main view render result */
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>" />
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?>Тестовое письмо</title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>

    <div style="background-color: green;">Приветик !</div>

     <?= Html::encode($model) ?>

    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

i get error "Undefined variable: model" - `<?= Html::encode($model) ?>`

how get parameters from compose()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a parameter in the layout file. But the parameter `model` is available only in the view.

So you have to change the code:

**mail/layouts/html.php**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\mail\BaseMailer;


/* @var $this \yii\web\View view component instance */
/* @var $message \yii\mail\MessageInterface the message being composed */
/* @var $content string main view render result */
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>" />
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?>Тестовое письмо</title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>

    <div style="background-color: green;">Приветик !</div>

     <?= $content ?>

    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

**mail/emailview.php**

```
<?= Html::encode($model) ?>
```

**php code**

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('emailview.php', ['model' => 'trtrtrtrt',])
 ->setFrom('ergegergerger@gmail.com')
 ->setTo('ergergergegerg@mail.ru')
 ->setSubject('TEST')
 ->send();
```

Comment: I edit you question, see you. Need  it - `mail/emailview.php` Ok?

Comment: @Fabrizio Caldarelli Very Thanks You! Have a nice on. )